# how to fix this error "Microsoft.Extensions.Azure: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=5.0.0.0,"

Tags: c#, .net, azure

there’s a problem that I didn’t understand where it came from because the script worked yesterday , I woke up and I found this problem that wasn’t there yesterday.
I’m working on a project (net 5.0) that contains Azure Function ,Entity Framework Core ,Microsoft Graph.

**Error :**

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Azure: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Impossibile trovare il file specificato.
```

Comment: is the error thrown from the function app ? Is your function app net5 ?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could not load file or assembly 'xxx'

This kind of problem is usually caused by version incompatibility. Upgrading or downgrading the assembly should be able to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm having this problem. I am adding packages, updating and downgrading to no avail. This is frustrating!

Answer (score 20):

If you updated your function to .NET 6, you need to use Azure Functions v4. Add this below to the function configuration in the Azure portal:

```
FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~4"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the correct answers. In my case I had value "~3", when I changed to "~4" the function started to work.

Comment: you should also modify this entry to .csproj file ```<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>```

Answer (score 9):

If you upgraded to .NET 6 and are seeing this when running the function locally, change your .csproj file:

```
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded from version3 to version 4 and it was working in my local environment, but not on Azure Portal. I removed:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
```

…but that caused another issue with dependency injection.

The solution was to change `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to ~4 in Azure Portal in Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this. I was unable to Publish from Visual Studio 2019 by using the normal Publish method. I followed these instructions and now I'm no longer missing any files.

https://demiliani.com/2020/03/26/a-quick-way-to-deploy-your-azure-functions-in-the-cloud/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Azure Function **v4** caused by an **outdated Azure Function Core Tools** ([download the latest version here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools).)

You can check your Function Core Tools version using `func version`. Be sure it is > 4.0 when using Azure Function v4!